# NodeJS: What is the best method that uses low bandwidth to send a big decimal array to a client?

Tags: node.js

I have a big decimal array, that I want to send to a client.
If I JSON.stringify the array and write it to file, it is 17MB.
After I manually rar that file, it is 1.9MB, so it could be much smaller.

I have read about UBJSON or compressing a JSON, but I don't know which method I should use in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what "decimal array" means exactly. Maybe a binary encoding may be the most natural choice.

Comment: for example:
[86.974609375,66.578125,47.8125,50.98828125]
I don't need a high precision. Two decimals should suffice.

Comment: @J.D. is there a maximum or minimum value for these numbers?

Comment: min = 0; max = 999

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a compressed filesize, why not compress it in nodejs before sending it to the client? You can use [zlib.gzip](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_creategzip_options) to get it into `.gz` format.  There are other file compression libraries for nodejs as well.